# How to estimate the given function using Rao Blackwellization approach?

Tags: monte-carlo, computational-statistics

I have a function $X$ which is lognormal (0,1)
and then another function 
$\log Y = 4 + 2 \log(X) + \epsilon$

where $\epsilon \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$

I want to estimate $E(Y|X)$ as a Rao Blackwellized estimator.

I tried to attempt the problem like this:

```
Nsim <- 10000
x <- rlnorm(Nsim)
z <- rnorm(Nsim,4+2*log(x),1)
```

Standard montecarlo estimator would be

```
sum(epx(z))/Nsim
```

I am confused about Rao Blackwellized estimator. Will it be just

```
p <- 4+2 * log(x)
sum(p)/Nsim
```